# Is image needed to rescale before predicting with model that trained with ImageDataGenerator(1./255)?

Tags: keras

After training model with ImageDataGenerator(1/255.), do I need to rescale image before predicting ? 
I thought it is necessary but experiment result said NO.

I trained a Resnet50 model which has 37 class on top layer.
Model was trained with ImageDataGenerator like this.

```py
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
generator=datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), data_folder),
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=256,
    classes=None,
    class_mode='categorical')

history = model.fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch=generator.n / 256, epochs=10)
```

Accuracy achieved 98% after 10 epochs on my train dataset.
The problem is, when i tried to predict each image in TRAIN dataset, prediction was wrong ( result is 33 whatever input image was )

```py
img_p = './data/pets/shiba_inu/shiba_inu_27.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_p, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224))

img_arr = np.zeros((1,224,224,3))
img_arr[0, :, :, :] = img / 255.
pred = model.predict(img_arr)
yhat = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)
```

yhat is 5, but y is 33

When I replace this line

```py
img_arr[0, :, :, :] = img / 255.
```

by this

```py
img_arr[0, :, :, :] = img
```

yhat is exactly 33.

Someone might suggest to use predict_generator() instead of predict(), but I want to understand what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

I knew what's wrong here.

I'm using Imagenet pretrained model, which DO NOT rescale image by divide it to 255. I have to use resnet50.preprocess_input before train/test.

preprocess_input function can be found here.
https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py

Answer (score 0):

You must do every preprocessing that you do on train data, on each data that you want to feed to your trained network. actually when, for example, you rescale train images and train a network, your network train to get a matrix with entries between 0 and 1 and find the proper category. so if after training phase, you feed an image without rescaling, you feed a matrix with entries between 0 and 255 to your trained network while your network did not learn how treat with such matrix.

Comment: Yes, I did it but result was wrong. Normally I create data generator by my self, and of course did rescale in both train and test data. Now I need data augmentation and trying to use ImageDataGenerator but this problem happened.

Comment: try to set shuffle = False.

Comment: shuffle = False didn't help

Answer (score 0):

If you are following pre-processing exactly same as at the time of training then, you might look at the part of your code where you are predicting class using `yhat = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)` my hunch is that there might be class mismatch in accordance to indexing, to check how your classes are indexed when you use `flow_from_directory` use `class_map = generator.class_indices` this will return you a dictionary which will show you how your classes are mapped against index.

Note: The reason I state this because I've faced similar problem, using Keras `flow_from_directory` doesn't sort classes and hence it's quite possible that your prediction class 1 lies on the index 10 while `np.argmax` will return you class 1'.